# How to find the numbers in three columns which are more than half the values of other column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, math

There are three columns X,Y and Z which has random values.

X,Y and Z values should not be less than half the value of each other.

Need help in math logic

```
  X    Y     Z
5461  919  8269
5400  5000 7000  <---
4000   1     35
```

The output should be 5400  5000 7000. In first row,Y is less than half of X and Z.In third row,Y and Z both are less than half of X.

Comment: updated! not looking for an output but logic to solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is simple: Just check for each value if it is less than half of the other two. Use apply to return `True` or `False` and then filter the rows using the obtained `boolean` values.

```py
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame([[
5461 , 919  ,8269],
[5400 , 5000, 7000], 
[4000 ,  1  ,   35]], columns = ['X','Y','Z'])
print(a)

def less(a,b,c):
    if a<b/2 or a<c/2:
        return True

def cond(a,b,c):
    if less(a,b,c) or less(b,a,c) or less(c,a,b):
        return False
    return True

a[a.apply(lambda x: cond(x['X'],x['Y'],x['Z']), axis=1)]
```

Output

```
      X     Y     Z
1  5400  5000  7000
```

Comment: great thanks! i appreciate your approach.Is there any other math logic which can be applied to solve this ? And please explain what cond() do here